# Contador JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Oi gente eu nao to sabendo como eu coloco um contador dentros dos if's a cada vez que tiver um aprovado ou reprovado pra depois eu mostrar em uma tabela a quantidade

```js
<script>
    function calcula_media(i)
    {
        var n1 = document.getElementById("n1_aluno_" + i).value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("n2_aluno_" + i).value;
        var media = document.getElementById("media_aluno_" + i);
        var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i);
        var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;
        var count = 0;

        if(calculo >= 70)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
            
        }
        else if(calculo >=30)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-rec'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Recuperaçao";
        }
       
        else
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Coloquei os contadores. Mas uma função que se diz calcular média não deveria contar aprovados, no mínimo o nome deveria mudar. O código acaba fazendo mais do que deveria e pode dar erros em algumas situações. Não vou tentar resolver todas questões.

Note que eu inicializei uma variável para cada tipo de contagem e incrementei o contador sempre que entra em cada um dos `if`s de acordo com o critério. Ainda precisa apresentar esses contadores no final de alguma forma.

```js
function calcula_media(i) {
    var n1 = document.getElementById("n1_aluno_" + i).value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2_aluno_" + i).value;
    var media = document.getElementById("media_aluno_" + i);
    var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i);
    var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;
    var contaAprovados = 0;
    var contaRecuperacao = 0;
    var contaReprovados = 0;
    if (calculo >= 70) {
        media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
        resultado.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
        contaAprovados++;
    } else if (calculo >=30) {
        media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-rec'>" + calculo + "</div>";
        resultado.innerHTML = "Recuperaçao";
        contaRecuperacao++;
    } else {
        media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
        resultado.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
        contaReprovados++;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Promotion.js).

Comment: O problema é que essas variáveis, por estarem dentro da função, nunca serão maiores que 1. :/

Comment: O problema não fala disto e colocar fora não é a solução, pode funcionar, mas será uma bela gambiarra. É o que eu falei, uma função que cuida de calcular a média não deveria fazer contagem de nada. Todo *design* disto está errado.

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado. Ela está pegando valores de inputs diferentes, de elementos com id's diferentes e calculando a média entre dois valores, inserindo o resultado em forma de div estilizada para cada situação, e quer contar de forma global o número de cada situação... aliás, apenas duas das 3 situações: aprovados e reprovados.

Comment: Não tem inputs na pergunta. Variáveis globais são bem erradas, todo mundo sabe disto. Tem solução melhor. Não consigo imaginar porque a terceira situação não é desejada, parece só mais um erro, a pergunta toda parece bem ruim e a decisão tomada em cima dela certamente será ruim.

Comment: Essa é a sua visão me parece bem deturpada. Tem input sim, se vc observar o código. As variáveis não precisam ser globais exatamente, e seu código não funciona. Então não deveria responder se não funciona. -1

Comment: O curioso é que a sua resposta recebe 2 votos positivos sendo que não funciona.

Comment: Eu vou até remover a minha resposta pq o mesmo AP já fez 2 perguntas com o mesmo assunto e me pareceu tudo confuso. Ela fez duas perguntas iguais com contas diferentes, mas isso os moderadores parecem não ver. Uma é [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/412221/8063) e a outra ela fez com um nome de usuário parecido, "Stella" sei la´oq.

Comment: Onde tem input? Você está tendo alucinações, qualquer um pode ver que não tem.

Comment: Ah, tem em outra pergunta. Eu respondi o que tinha aqui. De fato essa pergunta tá ruim. Moderadores não são onipresentes, se você vê alguma coisa e não faz nada a cullpa é sua de algo não ser feito. Você estava indo bem não reclamando mais, porque suas reclamaçõess são sempre baseadas em coisas que só estão na sua cabeça. A gente acha que a pessoa aprendeu, mas não é isso.