# Imprimir resultado do contador

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde.. Ta tudo funcionando certinho só que eu nao estou conseguindo colocar o valor dos contadores de alunos aprovados ou nao. alguem me ajuda por favor.. quero adicionar os valores la no final do html na parte:

td Alunos Reprovados /td

td AQUI TINHA QUE SAIR O VALOR DO CONTADOR DE REPROVADOS /td>

```js
    var aprovados = 0, reprovados = 0;
    function calcula_media(i)
    {
        var n1 = document.getElementById("n1_aluno_" + i).value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("n2_aluno_" + i).value;
        var media = document.getElementById("media_aluno_" + i);
        var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i);
        var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;
        
        

        if(calculo >= 70)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
            aprovados++;
            
        }
        else if(calculo >=30)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-rec'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Recuperaçao";
            
        }
       
        else
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
            reprovados++;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
          <h2>Notas Alunos</h2>
          <p>Digite as notas dos alunos e saiba se ele esta Aprovado, Recuperação ou Reprovado</p>
          <table class="table notas">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Estudante</th>
                <th>N1</th>
                <th>N2</th>
                <th>Média</th>
                <th>Resultado Final</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Stella</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_0"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_0">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Petronio</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_1"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_1">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Waldeir</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_2" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_2" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_2"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_2">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Arthur</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_3" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_3" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_3"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_3">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jean</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_4" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_4" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_4"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_4">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <table class="table resultado">
            <tbody>
        
            <tr>
                <td>Alunos Participantes</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Alunos Aprovados</td>
                <td> ?????</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Alunos Reprovados</td>
                <td>????? </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Media dos Alunos</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Stella, vc não resolveu a pergunta anterior que fez antes dessa e que trata do mesmo assunto rs... por favor, dá uma lida na página [tour] para conhecer a sistemática do site. É coisa rápida e vai te ajudar bastante a conhecer o funcionamento. Abs!

Comment: Dessa forma aí ficou muito complicado contar aprovados e reprovados. A sua outra pergunta, que não tinha esse código completo, ficou fácil sugerir contar os valores dessa forma, mas realmente não é.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um id às `<td>` que deseja inserir os valores, nesse exemplo adicionei os ids "total_aprovados" e "total_reprovados".

Foi necessário remover os contadores globais, pois à cada alteração nos `input` era adicionado mais um aos contadores, então coloquei pra refazer o cálculo à cada chamada, percorrendo os textos que estão nos resultados e comparando se estão como aprovados ou reprovados.

Para exibir esses valores, basta fazer como vc já tinha feito diversas vezes antes, usando o `innerHTML` ao elemento que deseja

```js
function calcula_media(i)
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById("n1_aluno_" + i).value;
  var n2 = document.getElementById("n2_aluno_" + i).value;
  var media = document.getElementById("media_aluno_" + i);
  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i);
  var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;
  var aprovados= 0;
  var reprovados = 0;

  if(calculo >= 70)
  {
    media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
    resultado.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
  }
  else if(calculo >=30)
  {
    media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-rec'>" + calculo + "</div>";
    resultado.innerHTML = "Recuperaçao";        
  }
  else
  {
    media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
    resultado.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
  }      
  for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    if(document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i).innerHTML == "Aprovado")
    {
      aprovados ++;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i).innerHTML == "Reprovado")
    {
      reprovados++;
    }
  }
        
  document.getElementById("total_aprovados").innerHTML = aprovados;
  document.getElementById("total_reprovados").innerHTML = reprovados;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Notas Alunos</h2>
  <p>Digite as notas dos alunos e saiba se ele esta Aprovado, Recuperação ou Reprovado</p>
  <table class="table notas">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Estudante</th>
        <th>N1</th>
        <th>N2</th>
        <th>Média</th>
        <th>Resultado Final</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Stella</td>
        <td><input id="n1_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
        <td><input id="n2_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
        <td><div id="media_aluno_0"> </div></td>
        <td><div id="resultado_aluno_0">-- </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Petronio</td>
        <td><input id="n1_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
        <td><input id="n2_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
        <td><div id="media_aluno_1"> </div></td>
        <td><div id="resultado_aluno_1">-- </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Waldeir</td>
        <td><input id="n1_aluno_2" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
        <td><input id="n2_aluno_2" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
        <td><div id="media_aluno_2"> </div></td>
        <td><div id="resultado_aluno_2">-- </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Arthur</td>
        <td><input id="n1_aluno_3" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
        <td><input id="n2_aluno_3" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
        <td><div id="media_aluno_3"> </div></td>
        <td><div id="resultado_aluno_3">-- </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jean</td>
        <td><input id="n1_aluno_4" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
        <td><input id="n2_aluno_4" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
        <td><div id="media_aluno_4"> </div></td>
        <td><div id="resultado_aluno_4">-- </div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
  <table class="table resultado">
    <tbody>    
      <tr>
        <td>Alunos Participantes</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alunos Aprovados</td>
        <td id="total_aprovados"> ?????</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alunos Reprovados</td>
        <td id="total_reprovados">????? </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Media dos Alunos</td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
        
  </table>
</div>
```