# HTML não está conseguindo pegar resultado do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Não estou conseguindo gerar o número de alunos aprovados e reprovados depois de colocar as notas. Onde eu errei?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="/_js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
    var aprovados = 0, reprovados = 0;
    
    function calcula_media(i)
    {
        var n1 = document.getElementById("n1_aluno_" + i).value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("n2_aluno_" + i).value;
        var media = document.getElementById("media_aluno_" + i);
        var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i);
        var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;
        var aprovados = document.getElementById("aprovados")
        var reprovados = document.getElementById("reprovados")
        
        

        if(calculo >= 70)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
            aprovados++;
            
        }
        else if(calculo >=30)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-rec'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Recuperaçao";
            
        }
       
        else
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
            reprovados++;
        }
    }
    
    aprovados.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + aprovados + "</div>";
    
    reprovados.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + reprovados + "</div>";

    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
          <h2>Notas Alunos</h2>
          <p>Digite as notas dos alunos e saiba se ele esta Aprovado, Recuperação ou Reprovado</p>
          <table class="table notas">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Estudante</th>
                <th>N1</th>
                <th>N2</th>
                <th>Média</th>
                <th>Resultado Final</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Stella</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_0" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(0)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_0"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_0">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Petronio</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_1" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(1)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_1"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_1">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Waldeir</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_2" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_2" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(2)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_2"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_2">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Arthur</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_3" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_3" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(3)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_3"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_3">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jean</td>
                <td><input id="n1_aluno_4" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                <td><input id="n2_aluno_4" type="number" value="0" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="10.0" onchange="calcula_media(4)"></td>
                <td><div id="media_aluno_4"> </div></td>
                <td><div id="resultado_aluno_4">-- </div></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <table class="table resultado">
            <tbody>
        
            <tr>
                <td>Alunos Participantes</td>
                <td> 5 </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Alunos Aprovados</td>
                <td> <div id="aprovados"></div></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Alunos Reprovados</td>
                <td> <div id="reprovados"></div> </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Media dos Alunos</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        
        </table>
        </div>

</body>
</html>a
```

Comment: Duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/412221/8063

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você não pode usar o nome "aprovados" e "reprovados" para duas variáveis diferentes. Use aprovador_contador e reprovador_contador para os contadores.

Para você recuperar as variáveis aprovados e reprovados fora da função, você não pode as redeclarar dentro do escopo da função.

Tire o "var" da frente da variável aprovados e reprovados quando você as define dentro da função. Dessa forma, você estará usando as variáveis globais que você definiu fora da função, em vez de limitar essas duas variáveis ao escopo da função.

```js
var aprovados_contador = 0, reprovados_contador = 0;
var aprovados, reprovados;

 function calcula_media(i)
    {
        var n1 = document.getElementById("n1_aluno_" + i).value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("n2_aluno_" + i).value;
        var media = document.getElementById("media_aluno_" + i);
        var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado_aluno_" + i);
        var calculo = (parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)) / 2;
        aprovados = document.getElementById("aprovados") // Alteração nessa linha
        reprovados = document.getElementById("reprovados") // Alteração nessa linha



        if(calculo >= 70)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-success'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Aprovado";
            aprovados_contador++;

        }
        else if(calculo >=30)
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-rec'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Recuperaçao";

        }

        else
        {
            media.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + calculo + "</div>";
            resultado.innerHTML = "Reprovado";
            reprovados_contador++;
        }
    }

aprovados.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + aprovados_contador + "</div>";
reprovados.innerHTML = "<div class='text-danger'>" + reprovados_contador + "</div>";
```

Comment: eu fiz as alteraçoes e mesmo assim nao aparece  a quantidade de alunos aprovados ou reprovados

Comment: Fiz uma mudança na minha explicação, tenta fazer como ficou agora e vê se funciona.

Comment: continua nao funcionando, mas obrigada por tentar ajudar.. eu ja nem sei oq faço mais pra esse trem funcionar kkk